# sed one-liner to delete everything between a pair of brackets?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am working with some text that is full of stuff between brackets [] that I don't want. Since I can delete the brackets myself, I don't need the one-liner to do that for me, but I do need a one-liner that will remove everything between them.

What about parentheses () instead of brackets?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Replace `[some text]` by the empty string. Assuming you don't want to parse nested brackets, the `some text` can't contain any brackets.

```
sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g'
```

Note that in the bracket expression `[^][]` to match anything but `[` or `]`, the `]` must come first. Normally a `]` would end the character set, but if it's the first character in the set (here, after the `^` complementation character), the `]` stands for itself.

If you do want to parse nested brackets, or if the bracketed text can span multiple lines, sed isn't the right tool.

Comment: thanks, @Gilles... btw, it can span multiple lines, but I'm using a Perl script to join lines...

Comment: @ixtmixilix: If you have a Perl script, you can make it remove the bracketed text as well. In Perl, you can write `s/\[[^\[\]]*\]//g` (i.e. use backslashes to escape the members of the character set).

Comment: @Gilles could you explain more about [^][] exactly plz. thank you

Comment: @arashams `[…]` = character set. `^` as the first character means to complement the set. `]` would normally be mark the end of the set, but if it's the first character other than `^`, it's an ordinary character — an empty set or the complement of the empty set isn't permitted. Then `[` is ordinary and `]` ends the set.

Comment: @Gilles tnx for your help but still i dont get it :(  what dose that mean? "^ as the first character means to complement the set" i mean what is it doing ? for example is it matched to all contents?

Answer (score 13):

The command `sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'`will do parentheses instead of brackets.