# Renaming files to remove parenthesized strings

Tags: files, rename

I have a collection of files with names like these:

```
Ace of Aces (Europe).mp4
Action Fighter (USA, Europe) (v1.2).mp4
Addams Family, The (Europe).mp4
Aerial Assault (USA).mp4
After Burner (World).mp4
Air Rescue (Europe).mp4
Aladdin (Europe).mp4
Alex Kidd - High-Tech World (USA, Europe).mp4
Alex Kidd in Miracle World (USA, Europe) (v1.1).mp4
Alex Kidd in Shinobi World (USA, Europe).mp4
Alex Kidd - The Lost Stars (World).mp4
Alf (USA).mp4
Alien 3 (Europe).mp4
Alien Storm (Europe).mp4
Alien Syndrome (USA, Europe).mp4
Altered Beast (USA, Europe).mp4
American Baseball (Europe).mp4
American Pro Football (Europe).mp4
Andre Agassi Tennis (Europe).mp4
Arcade Smash Hits (Europe).mp4
Assault City (Europe) (Light Phaser).mp4
```

(I have these filenames listed in a text file.)

I have to get away from parentheses, so I would like to rename the files
to remove the parentheses and the text between them,
so the filenames will be as follows:

```
Ace of Aces.mp4
Action Fighter.mp4
Addams Family, The.mp4
Aerial Assaul.mp4
After Burner.mp4
Air Rescue.mp4
Aladdi.mp4
Alex Kidd - High-Tech World.mp4
Alex Kidd in Miracle World.mp4
Alex Kidd in Shinobi World.mp4
Alex Kidd - The Lost Stars.mp4
Alf.mp4
Alien 3.mp4
Alien Storm.mp4
Alien Syndrome.mp4
Altered Beast.mp4
American Baseball.mp4
American Pro Footbal.mp4
Andre Agassi Tennis.mp4
Arcade Smash Hits.mp4
Assault City.mp4
```

Ideally, any solution should alert me if I have, for example, files like
`Aladdin (Europe).mp4` and `Aladdin (Asia).mp4`, 
or `Ghostbusters (1984).mp4` and `Ghostbusters (2016).mp4`,
and not destroy any files.

Comment: Are you on a gnu/linux system with the "rename" or "prename" utility?

Comment: Also, are you renaming files, or editing a text file?

Comment: I only need rename files, and yes there is rename.

Comment: What happens if you have `Aladdin (Europe).mp4` and `Aladdin (Asia).mp4`, for example?

Comment: it could be a problem because i have to get away all things from parenthesis

Comment: or maybe without txt file i need to remove from the names all things in various parenthesis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed one-liner to delete everything between a pair of brackets?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/sed-one-liner-to-delete-everything-between-a-pair-of-brackets)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the currently-listed sed one-liner because the OP is not editing text, but renaming files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename` commandline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574):

Use this :

```
rename 's/\s*\([^\)]+\)//g' *.mp4
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`, (also checks for conflicts):

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '*' '${f//[[:space:]]#[(]*[)]}'
```

Remove `-n` or replace with `-v` when happy.

With `//`, we remove *all* occurrences of `(...)`, but since the  `*` is *greedy*, there will only be at most one match anyway. On `1 (2) 3 (4)`, it would match `" (2) 3 (4)"`. You can make the `*` non-greedy by using the `S` parameter expansion flag:

```
zmv -n '*' '${(S)f//[[:space:]]#[(]*[)]}'
```

Or replace `*` with `[^)]#` (0 or more non-`)`s).